# How to enable online editing of repository source in git server?

Tags: git, github, git-bare

We have a private git server that contains our repositories. it works fine, but we want to add online source code view , editing .. etc ( like GitHub.com does), how can we provide these features in our server ?

As far as I know, generally the repositories in git servers are bare. so how do websites like [github](https://github.com) and [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) provide online editing feature ?

Thanks.

Comment: They use git. When "saving" the file from the web UI, they add, commit and push the file to the repository, just like you would do with a text editor from your machine.

Comment: @JBNizet Did you mean they clone the original repositories , add, commit and push it back ? I think it's not efficient way especially for large repositories

Comment: I don't know exactly how they do it, because I don't work there, and don't know all the gory details, but that's what they "logically" do. Technically, maybe they have a git api allowing to do that without actually cloning the whole repo, or maybe they use partial clones, or whatever. But they obviously must know the deep, internal workings of git to implement github or bitbucket in an efficient way. My point is that they don't just edit files. They add commits to the repo, as if you had edited the file with a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/). It's very similar to GitHub, but there's an open-source edition you can deploy on your own servers for free.

Comment: Thank you for response, but we already have a server, and we want to add this feature to our existing one

Comment: I'm not sure I understand… Do you mean you want to re-implement these features on your own? GitLab would work fine on *your* existing server.

Comment: I think what he wants to say is that he wants to learn how these work under the hood other than implementing them?

Comment: @Arkanosis yes I want to re-implement them

Comment: @Noobs, implementing those features is a very big job. Is there any particular reason you don't want to use an existing open-source product?

Comment: Hi @Chris, I really appreciate your effort. Actually, it was a part of my graduation project, sorry for being late, but somehow I didn't get a notification.